# How to call a class that is in Kotlin format, through Intent in Java?

Tags: java, kotlin, android-intent

I'm doing a project that has two classes: a Java class called `a` and another Kotlin class called `b`.
In Java's `MainActivity`, I want to go to the class called `b.kt`
So how do you do this through Intent?
I've tried it in several ways, such as:

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), b.kt));

startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), b::class.kt));

startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), b.kt.class));
```

But error always happens.
Please, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be `b.class`. From the Java point of view, it doesn't even know if the class is a Kotlin class or a Java class, so the syntax is the same as if it's a Java class.

Also, the `b` class should be a subclass of Activity.

By the way, it is convention to *always* start class names with a capital letter. If you follow the conventions, it will make your code easier to understand and you'll be less likely to make mistakes.